# map.find implementation

Tags: stl, dictionary, find

I'm trying to implement map.find myself, because I must to search among regexps.
But my code works to long. Help plz. How can I improve the code? Can I add integer to iterator in other way? Built-in function works more than 10 times faster.

```
iterator find (string toFind)
{
    iterator begin=mainMap.begin();
    int L=0;
    int R=mainMap.size();
    iterator M;
    while (L!=R)
    {
        M=begin;
        addition(&M,((R+L)/2));
        if (match (&(*M).first, &toFind))
            return M;
        if (toFind<(*M).first)
        {
            R=(R+L)/2;
        }
        else 
            L=(R+L)/2+1;
    }
    return mainMap.end();
}

void addition (iterator* it, int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++, (*it)++)
    {
    }
}

bool match (const string* expression, const string* line)
{
    return *expression==*line;
}
```

Comment: e.g. if map contains { "a* 5", "b* 4", "c 5" }
then:

find("any")= iterator on the element "a* 5";
find("bingo")= iterator on the element "b* 4";
find("nothing")= iterator on the past-the-end

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to implement a new find algorithm. It is enough to pass a comparison functor to the map.

Something like

```
struct MyLessThan
{
    bool operator(const string& left, const string& right )(
      //Your implementation of less than, where you can use regular expressions
      //Don't forget it should have strict weak ordering

    }
};
```

and then define the map as (using the functor as a template argument)

```
std::map<string, VALUETYPE, MyLessThan> myMap;
```

with VALUETYPE the type of the values of the map.

Comment: Do you mean, that if in the map exists non-comparable element with searchable, then find returns it?